# VBA SQL Where IS NULL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Im trying to create a VBA sql string with the where clause using inputs from an access form. I need the code to still run properly even if one of the user inputs is null/unselected. The code below runs correctly when all user inputs have been selected but when one input is null/unselected the query ends up pulling back all the records in the table.

```vb
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT qry_1.field1, qry_1.field2, qry_1.field3 INTO recordset FROM qry_1" & _

" WHERE ((qry_1.Field1) IS NULL OR (qry_1.Field1) = '" & [Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1] & "') " &_
" AND ((qry_1.Field2) IS NULL OR (qry_1.Field2) = '" & [Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_2] & "' ) " & _
" AND ((qry_1.Field3) IS NULL OR (qry_1.Field3) = '" & [Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_3] & "')    ;"


DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query instead of concatenation.  This is highly vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: You should check whether the form field is null, not whether the query field is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to escape single apostrophes in the text for two reasons

1. You might get an invalid SQL statement if you don't.
2. A nasty user could can inject evil code (see: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Therefore I use this function

```vb
Public Function SqlStr(ByVal s As String) As String
    'Input: s=""      Returns: NULL
    'Input: s="abc"   Returns: 'abc'
    'Input: s="x'y"   Returns: 'x''y'

    If s = "" Then
        SqlStr = "NULL"
    Else
        SqlStr = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
End Function
```

To account for empty entries, create the condition like this:

```vb
Dim cond As String, sql As String

If Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]) <> "" Then
    cond = "qry_1.field1 = " & SqlStr(Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]))
End If
If Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_2]) <> "" Then
    If cond <> "" Then cond = cond & " AND "
    cond = cond & "qry_1.field2 = " & SqlStr(Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_2]))
End If
If Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_3]) <> "" Then
    If cond <> "" Then cond = cond & " AND "
    cond = cond & "qry_1.field3 = " & SqlStr(Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_3]))
End If
sql = "SELECT qry_1.field1, qry_1.field2, qry_1.field3 INTO recordset FROM qry_1"
If cond <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " WHERE " & cond
End If
```

This assumes that you want to test a condition only when the corresponding field is not empty.

---

If you have date constants, format them the Access-SQL way as `#2018-08-21#` with

```
Format$(date, "\#yyyy-MM-dd\#")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ran into an issue when one of the conditions was a date time field. Do i need to rewrite the code above or format the field in qry1?

Comment: Added an explanation for date constants.

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.RunSQL` is for action queries (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`).

To answer the question, here is what I would do:

```
Nz(Field1,Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]))=Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1])
```

That will create equality if either `Field1` or `[Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]` is NULL without breaking the rest of the query.

To use that in VBA:

```
"Nz(Field1,'" & Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]) & "')='" & Nz([Forms]![frm_Parameters]![cmbx_1]) & "'"
```

Also see comment in Olivier Jacot-Descombes answer about taking single quotes in your strings into account.